# Performance impact of calling a SProc from another SProc in SQL Server

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Does calling one stored procedure from within another stored procedure impact performance at all? I have been unable to find any answers regarding this. If it does negatively impact performance, I suppose the only alternative is to combine the procedures as one larger one.

I know it negatively impacts performance to call functions within Sprocs (it's better to just retype the code within the SProc) due to the way SQL plans query statistics, but I would imagine that is only true for functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen a performance problem with a stored procedure calling another stored procedure per se.

However, I have seen transactions being far larger than necessary - causing serious performance issues - because developers expanded the inner stored procedure without understanding the consequences.

Here's another problem example: there's a "nice" stored procedure that is almost perfect for many scenarios, the coder uses it all over the place. However, the stored procedure actually returns double the number of columns 90% of the callers actually require. The calling code is not optimized.

This is why stored procedures should have only simple set-based logic, and why I'm against complex stored procedures with procedural logic and calls to other stored procedures.

So... best avoided IMHO.

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly. I'm mainly going for code re-usability and cleanliness with the nested stored procedures. I have a complex database structure (due to the requirements of my data) and am a real stickler about both performance and user readability.

Comment: No worries. Re-usability makes perfect sense in C# or Java etc, but it is more difficult in SQL and can lead to the performance problems like the one I've outlined. However, if you're careful and keep the SQL simple you may well be fine.

Comment: I'm confused about how that would cause further problems, if calling one within another doesn't alter execution statistics. It would be analogous to calling one C# class from within another. The same theory of writing a good procedure would apply, paying close attention to execution statistics.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I've added another example. Ultimately, writing SQL and writing C# should be very different exercises.

Comment: I'm not being religious about stored procedures calling stored procedures - there will be many cases where it is fine. Just worth investigating the down sides, which is what I'm trying to highlight.

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing. I think if you could do all the outer proc does with a single statement, the cost of executing extra statements can be very considerable (just like in C# you may gain a lot by inlining logic if the data it operates on is already in context, whereas a separate function would have to spend most of its time on locating it in some data structure). But such considerations aside, I wish someone could say something concrete about the absolute overhead involved simply in transferring control. I imagine it is large compared to our C# world.